# Type 'RouteProp<ScopeNavParamList, keyof ScopeNavParamList>' is not assignable to type 'RouteProp<ScopeNavParamList, "DashboardIndex">'

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to annotate `screenOptions` types on `StackNavigator` but unfortunately, the compiler does not accept the annotation. The compiler complains:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Omit<DefaultRouterOptions<string> & { children: ReactNode; screenListeners?: Partial<{ transitionStart: EventListenerCallback<StackNavigationEventMap, "transitionStart">; ... 7 more ...; beforeRemove: EventListenerCallback<...>; }> | ((props: { ...; }) => Partial<...>) | undefined; screenOptions?: StackNavigationOptions | ... 1 more ... | undefined; defaultScreenOptions?: StackNavigationOptions | ... 1 more ... | undefined; } & StackRouterOptions & StackNavigationConfig, "initialRouteName" | ... 3 more ... | "defaultScreenOptions"> & DefaultRouterOptions<...> & { ...; }, context?: any): ReactElement<...> | ... 1 more ... | null', gave the following error.
    Type '({ navigation, route }: NavigatorProps) => StackNavigationOptions' is not assignable to type 'StackNavigationOptions | ((props: { route: RouteProp<ScopeNavParamList, keyof ScopeNavParamList>; navigation: any; }) => StackNavigationOptions) | undefined'.
      Type '({ navigation, route }: NavigatorProps) => StackNavigationOptions' is not assignable to type '(props: { route: RouteProp<ScopeNavParamList, keyof ScopeNavParamList>; navigation: any; }) => StackNavigationOptions'.
        Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
          Type '{ route: RouteProp<ScopeNavParamList, keyof ScopeNavParamList>; navigation: any; }' is not assignable to type 'NavigatorProps'.
            Types of property 'route' are incompatible.
              Type 'RouteProp<ScopeNavParamList, keyof ScopeNavParamList>' is not assignable to type 'RouteProp<ScopeNavParamList, "DashboardIndex">'.
                Type 'RouteProp<ScopeNavParamList, keyof ScopeNavParamList>' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{ key: string; name: "DashboardIndex"; path?: string | undefined; }>'.
                  Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
                    Type 'keyof ScopeNavParamList' is not assignable to type '"DashboardIndex"'.
                      Type '"HashesIndex"' is not assignable to type '"DashboardIndex"'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: PropsWithChildren<Omit<DefaultRouterOptions<string> & { children: ReactNode; screenListeners?: Partial<{ transitionStart: EventListenerCallback<StackNavigationEventMap, "transitionStart">; ... 7 more ...; beforeRemove: EventListenerCallback<...>; }> | ((props: { ...; }) => Partial<...>) | undefined; screenOptions?: StackNavigationOptions | ... 1 more ... | undefined; defaultScreenOptions?: StackNavigationOptions | ... 1 more ... | undefined; } & StackRouterOptions & StackNavigationConfig, "initialRouteName" | ... 3 more ... | "defaultScreenOptions"> & DefaultRouterOptions<...> & { ...; }>, context?: any): ReactElement<...> | ... 1 more ... | null', gave the following error.
    Type '({ navigation, route }: NavigatorProps) => StackNavigationOptions' is not assignable to type 'StackNavigationOptions | ((props: { route: RouteProp<ScopeNavParamList, keyof ScopeNavParamList>; navigation: any; }) => StackNavigationOptions) | undefined'.
      Type '({ navigation, route }: NavigatorProps) => StackNavigationOptions' is not assignable to type '(props: { route: RouteProp<ScopeNavParamList, keyof ScopeNavParamList>; navigation: any; }) => StackNavigationOptions'.
```

The implementation:

```
type ScopeNavParamList = {
    DashboardIndex: { title: string };
    HashesIndex: { title: string };
    NewHashes: { title: string };
    AccountIndex: { title: string };
};

type NavigatorProps = StackScreenProps<ScopeNavParamList, "DashboardIndex">;

const ScopeNavigator = createStackNavigator<ScopeNavParamList>();
const screenOptions = ({navigation, route }: NavigatorProps) : StackNavigationOptions => {

    return {
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: Colors.background,
            elevation: 0,
        },
        headerTitleAlign: "center",
        headerTitleStyle: {
            fontFamily: Typography.poppinsMedium,
            color: Colors.primaryDarker,
            fontSize: 22
    
        },
        cardStyle: {
            backgroundColor: Colors.background
        },
    }    
}


export function DashboardNav() {
    return (
        <ScopeNavigator.Navigator initialRouteName="DashboardIndex" screenOptions={screenOptions} >
            <ScopeNavigator.Screen name="DashboardIndex" component={Dashboard} />
        </ScopeNavigator.Navigator>
    );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a type error on your screenOptions function's parameters.
try to remove your custom NavigatorProps

```
const screenOptions = ({navigation, route }) : StackNavigationOptions => {
        return {
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: Colors.background,
                elevation: 0,
            },
            headerTitleAlign: "center",
            headerTitleStyle: {
                fontFamily: Typography.poppinsMedium,
                color: Colors.primaryDarker,
                fontSize: 22
        
            },
            cardStyle: {
                backgroundColor: Colors.background
            },
        }    
    }
```

Comment: without `NavigatorProps` it will be not typesafe anymore.